# KONG ingress in GKE with private IP

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

When I try to create kong ingress controller in GKE its actually creating public-facing layer 4 tcp load balancer, is there any way we can block the external IP and use private IP

Comment: Hello, have you tried to [add the annotation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/internal-load-balancing#config): `networking.gke.io/load-balancer-type: "Internal"` to your `Service` of type `LoadBalancer` that is exposing your Kong Ingress controller?

Comment: yes. I tried with the same. But it only works with gce ingress

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering the question:

> How can I create an `Ingress` resource used by `Kong Ingress Controller` that is available only through the private/internal IP with `GKE` cluster?

You can do it by following below steps:

- Modify and apply the `Kong Ingress` controller manifest.
- Create and apply `Ingress` resource that will be used by `Kong`.

> A side note!
>
> `Ingress` controllers like `nginx-ingress`, `kong`, etc. are using the `Service` of type `Loadbalancer` (Layer 4) for incoming traffic.

---

#### Modify and apply the `Kong Ingress` controller manifest

`Kong` github page:

- *[Github.com: Kong: Kubernetes Ingress controller: Get started](https://github.com/Kong/kubernetes-ingress-controller#get-started)*

As stated previously, you will need to download, modify and apply the `Kong Ingress` controller manifest. **By default your controller will be exposed to the external sources** but you can change this behavior by specifying following annotation (in your `Service` of type `LoadBalancer` of your downloaded manifest):

- `networking.gke.io/load-balancer-type: "Internal"`

You will need to edit the `Service` like below:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    networking.gke.io/load-balancer-type: "Internal" # <-- IMPORTANT, ADD THIS
  name: kong-proxy
  namespace: kong
spec:
  ports:
  - name: proxy
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8000
  - name: proxy-ssl
    port: 443
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8443
  selector:
    app: ingress-kong
  type: LoadBalancer
```

After spawning modified `YAML` manifest your `Service` responsible for incoming traffic should look like below:

- `$ kubectl get service -n kong`

```sh
NAME                      TYPE           CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
kong-proxy                LoadBalancer   10.8.5.66    10.156.0.92   80:32764/TCP,443:32002/TCP   14m
kong-validation-webhook   ClusterIP      10.8.6.32    <none>        443/TCP                      14m
```

As you can see the `External IP` of your `kong-proxy` is within the `CIDR` of your `GKE` nodes. You will need to send the request to this particular address within the subnet.

---

#### Create and apply `Ingress` resource that will be used by `Kong`

To check if your newly created `Ingress` controller is behaving correctly you can check with below example:

- `$ kubectl create deployment nginx --image=nginx`
- `$ kubectl expose deployment nginx --port=80 --type=ClusterIP`

`Ingress` resource `YAML` manifest will be following for this example:

```yaml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: kong-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "kong" # <-- IMPORTANT, ADD THIS
spec:
  rules:
  - host:
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: nginx
          servicePort: 80
```

`ingress.class` is used to tell your `Kubernetes` cluster which `Ingress` controller should handle this resource.

After applying above resource you should be able to see it by invoking:

- `$ kubectl get ingress kong-ingress`

```
NAME           CLASS    HOSTS   ADDRESS       PORTS   AGE
kong-ingress   <none>   *       10.156.0.92   80      16m
```

As you can see your `kong-ingress` is available on the **internal IP** the same as the `Service` of type `LoadBalancer`.

You can use other `VM` within the subnet to check if it's working by running:

- `curl 10.156.0.92`

The `NGINX` welcome page should be seen.

---

Additional resources:

- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Concepts: Services networking: Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/)*
- *[Cloud.google/com: Kubernetes Engine: Docs: How to: Internal Load Balancing](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/internal-load-balancing)*

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly the issue here, I think that you should be able to use internal L7 Ingress then. Here's a config example:

https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/internal-load-balance-ingress

But check if you meet the requirements:
https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/internal-load-balance-ingress#requirements